# Multiple version of library, how to compile with GCC/g++ whit out version number

Tags: gcc, g++, rpm, deb

I am working on a library in C, let us call it ninja. 
Ninja depends upon some under laying libraries (which we also provide) (e.g jutsu, goku, bla). 
These are all placed in a shared library folder, let us say /usr/lib/secret/.
The clients whom are using this project wants to be able to havde ninja version 1 and 2 laying side by side, this it not so hard. The problem comes when ninja 1 dependes up on for instance jutsu 1 and ninja 2 depends upon jutsu 3. How the h... do we/I do so so that when installing ninja from our package repository. It knows the correct version of jutsu. Of course the rpm/deb package should depend upon the correct version of the jutsu package.

so what we want is when, we execute for instance zypper in ninja. and it installs and compiles on the system, it knows which jutsu library to take with out been given a version number.

So we in the make file don't have to do this:

```
gcc ninja.c -o ninja -L /usr/local/lib/secret/ -l jutsu_2
```

But just

```
gcc ninja.c -o ninja -L /usr/local/lib/secret/ -l jutsu
```

NOTE: I know it is random to use ninja and so on, but I am not allowed to publish the real library names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an SONAME. Describing all the steps necessary is probably too large a scope for a good StackOverflow answer, but I can give an overview and point to some documentation.

An SONAME is a special data field inside a shared library. It is typically used to indicate compatibility with other versions of the same library; if two different versions of a shared library have the same SONAME, the linkers will know that either one can fill the dependency on that library. If they have a different SONAME, they can't.

Example: I have `libdns88` and `libbind-dev` version `1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u1` installed on a Debian wheezy system. I build a binary called `samurai` with `-ldns`. The GNU linker finds "`libdns.so`" in my library search path and dynamically links `samurai` with it. It reads the SONAME field from `libdns.so` (which is a symlink to `libdns.so.88.1.1`). The SONAME there is "`libdns.so.88`".

```
$ objdump -p /usr/lib/libdns.so | grep SONAME
  SONAME               libdns.so.88
```

The libdns developers (or maybe packagers) chose that SONAME to indicate that any version 88.* of libdns is expected to be binary compatible with any other version 88.*. They use that same SONAME for all versions with a compatible ABI. When the ABI had a change, they changed the SONAME to `libdns.so.89`, and so on. (Most well-managed libraries don't change their ABI that often.)

So the library dependency written into the `samurai` binary is just `libdns.so.88`. When I run `samurai` later, the dynamic linker/loader looks for a file called "`libdns.so.88`" instead of just "`libdns.so`".

Also by convention, the name of an rpm or deb package should change when the SONAME of the library contained changes. That's why there is a `libdns88` package separate from the `libdns100` package, and they can be installed side by side without interfering with each other. My `samurai` package will have a dependency on "`libdns88`" and I can expect that any package called `libdns88` will have a compatible ABI to the one I built it against. Tools like `dpkg-shlibdeps` make it simple to create the right shared library package dependencies when SONAMEs and versioned symbols are used.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html